# How to create a narrowing chevron in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

This is a chevron :

```css
.shape {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before, .shape:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
    top: 10px;
}
.shape:before {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: skewY(20deg);
}
.shape:after {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: skewY(-20deg);
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

What I basically need to create is this :

[image]

How can we stretch the chevron on hover?

Answer (score 8):

A slightly different approach: instead of using skew, use rotate + translate:

```css
.shape {
    height: 200px;
    width: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape::before, .shape::after {
    border-radius: 20px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
    top: 50%;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
.shape::before {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
.shape::after {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    right: 0;
}
.shape:hover::before {
    transform: translateX(15px) rotate(45deg);
}
.shape:hover::after {
    transform: translateX(-15px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: I need them to stretch  on hover

Comment: I need them to stretch downwards

Comment: Then add some vertical translation using `translateY()`.

Answer (score 4):

Below is another approach to achieve the chevron shape and make it narrower on hover. It uses a skewed parent container and one reverse skewed child.

> Note: The other methods cause the `hover` effect to be triggered even when hovering the white area because the container is a rectangle and its area includes the white portion. The below snippet does not have that problem as here the container itself is skewed.

```css
div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(10deg);
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  -moz-transform-origin: left;
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  transform: skewY(-10deg) skewY(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  -moz-transform-origin: left;
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;  
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(20deg);
  transform: skewY(20deg);
}
div:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-20deg) skewY(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-20deg) skewY(-20deg);
  transform: skewY(-20deg) skewY(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

> Credits to [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki) for helping to figure out the initial issue with transitions on the second snippet.

---

This is an alternate way to achieve the chevron shape and the hover effect.Here the chevron shape is created by using linear-gradients for background. On hover, the gradient angles and positions are modified to produce a narrowing effect.

```css
div{
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(70deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-70deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(20deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), -moz-linear-gradient(-20deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), linear-gradient(-20deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);
    background-size:50% 100%, 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% -22px, 100% -22px;
}
div:hover{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(60deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-60deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);    
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), -moz-linear-gradient(-30deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);
    background: linear-gradient(30deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%), linear-gradient(-30deg, white 30%, red 30%, red 70%, white 70%);
    background-size:50% 100%, 50% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%, 100% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

> Below is the original answer which was down-voted (for whatever reason) just in case it is useful for future readers.

The chevron shape is created by using two borders and an element rotated by 45 degrees. On hover, the element is further rotated allow the Y-axis to produce a narrowing effect.

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
div:hover {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(55deg) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(55deg) rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotateY(55deg) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A *very* quick mock up of your example would be:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrap {
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin: 50px;

}
.top,
.bottom {
  left: 10px;
    transition:all 0.8s;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 200px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  top: -41%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 200px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  bottom: -41%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.wrap:hover .top,
.wrap:hover .bottom {
  left: 30px;
}
.wrap:hover .top {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
  top: -35%;
}
.wrap:hover .bottom {
  bottom: -35%;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding positioning to keyframes is making the chevron shiver! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just skew them by a greater angle on hover.

```css
.shape {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before, .shape:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
    top: 10px;
}
.shape:before {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: skewY(20deg);
}
.shape:after {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: skewY(-20deg);
    right: 0;
}
.shape:hover {
    height: 230px;
}
.shape:hover:before {
    transform: skewY(30deg);
}
.shape:hover:after {
    transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
.shape, .shape:before, .shape:after, .shape:hover, .shape:hover:before, .shape:hover:after {
    transition: 0.5s ease all;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:hover` and increase/decrease `skewY`:

```css
.shape {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shape:before, .shape:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    background: red;
    top: 10px;
}
.shape:before {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: skewY(20deg);
}
.shape:after {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: skewY(-20deg);
    right: 0;
}
.shape:hover {
    height: 220px;
    width: 250px;
}
.shape:hover:after {
    transform: skewY(-40deg);
}
.shape:hover:before {
    transform: skewY(40deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```