# Arrow out border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

so i have a page that looks like this:

[image: how it looks now]

But i want the lines to be in the shape of a arrows like:
[image: what i would like to have]

Is this posible???

My current css:

```
#show_length{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 99%;
}

#show_length2{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 20%;
}
```

And:

```
<div id="show_length">25m</div>
<div id="show_length2">2.5m</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that would definitely be possible. You could use a rotated pseudo-element with borders on only two sides. You can check the third snippet in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299464/how-to-create-a-narrowing-chevron-in-css/28299645#28299645) answer for idea on how to create the arrow-head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something almost like that using `pseudo-elements`

```css
#show_length{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
#show_length:after{
    content:">";
    position:absolute;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:265px;
    margin-top:2px;
    font-size:30px;
}

#show_length2{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="show_length">25m</div>
<div id="show_length2">2.5m</div>
```

Comment: I see :) Thank you very much! Need to wait 5 minuts to accept answer.